# Neovim installation issue on Mac

Tags: macos, neovim

I have a problem with neovim installation,
when I run the the command:
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim-macos.tar.gz
tar xzf nvim-macos.tar.gz
./nvim-macos/bin/nvim
I get neovim working as usual but when I close that instance the nvim command disappear.
Also what I get are two folders in my home directory: nvim-macos and nvim-macos.
If I run Nvim via the nvim-macos folder it work as usual.

I have previusly installed neovim and than override the installation, do you guys know how I can get a new clan installation, what I have to delete and so on?

I've tried to install neovim via home-brew but it has no effect (it give the error: "Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!") also I tried to manually search and delete some neovim folder like ~/.config/Nvim.

Comment: Please read [how to format a literal block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and reformat your question so it is readable. You also say there are two folders in your home directory, `nvim-macos and nvim-macos`, but those names are identical. So you must have copy/pasted the wrong folder name for one of them. For a question of this nature you should also tell us the macOS version. Basically, you haven't gotten any answers because no one can make sense of the problem.